# Icon is not getting displayed in notification in Android nougat

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.1-nougat

I researched about this and found out that `addAction (int icon, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent)` is deprecated, so I used `addAction (Notification.Action action)` . In both the cases, icon cant be seen.

```
NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_share, "", pendingIntent).build();

notificationBuilder.addAction(action);
```

The text seems to be working though, but I have left it blank, hence there is an empty space below the main image, where icon is supposed to be displayed

Comment: .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()) use it in notificationCompat object and then you can see icons

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not an error, but a change in the design with Android Nougat. Icons defined by ***addAction (Notification.Action action)*** are not any more displayed by devices. They still are required for older devices and Android Wear devices!

Quoting [android developers google blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/notifications-in-android-n.html)

> You’ll note that the icons are not present in the new notifications;
>   instead more room is provided for the labels themselves in the
>   constrained space of the notification shade. However, the notification
>   action icons are still required and continue to be used on older
>   versions of Android and on devices such as Android Wear.
>
> If you’ve been building your notification with
>   NotificationCompat.Builder and the standard styles available to you
>   there, you’ll get the new look and feel by default with no code
>   changes required.

Comment: Well, that sucks.

Comment: What is the solution now? Please I need more clarification

Comment: @MarwaEltayeb there is no solution; action icons are gone.