# My notification action icons don't be shown in android 7

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

My notification action icons don't be shown in android 7 (N)! Is it a change in Android 7? Can not I use them anymore?
I see this problem when I run my app (That targeted API23) on Nexus 6P with Android 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icon is not getting displayed in notification in Android nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503972/icon-is-not-getting-displayed-in-notification-in-android-nougat)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, Google redesigned notifications in Android 7 and abort icon for actions.
You can also check this:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#notification_enhancements